# C++: float calculado não entra no if

Tags: c++, if, float, divisão

olá, preciso de ajuda. 
Não estou a conseguir entrar no condicional "if" com um número flutuante obtido após uma operação.
No código abaixo quando declaro o valor 0.05 entra no "if", mas quando faço a obtenção do 0.05 através de uma subtração de dois float não entra no "if" e preciso de operar valores para resolver o meu exercício.

```html
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    float v1=2;
    float v2=1.95;

    float diferenca = v1-v2;
    cout << diferenca << endl;
    
    if (diferenca == 0.05){
        
        cout << "entrou"<< endl; // NAO ESTA A ENTRAR !
    }
}
```

Comment: Um número decimal na representação `float` é naturalmente impreciso por definição da forma de representação. Não utilize igualdade para comparação de um `float`. De preferência teste um intervalo de valores. No seu caso algo do tipo: `if (diferenca <= 0.05){`. Se for necessária precisão utilize alguma biblioteca de representação decimal, "Bignum C++ library" por exemplo.

Comment: Na realidade creio que para seu problema o melhor seria considerar uma faixa de erro, por exemplo: `if (diferenca >= 04999 && diferenca <= 0.05001){`. Ou ainda: `if (round(diferenca* 100) == 5){`.